# Why isn't the menu showing up? - Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout, tkinter-menu

I'm trying to do a menu using tkinter. But when I run the code, the window appears, but the menu doesn't. I'm getting no errors.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")

menu = Menu(root)

file_menu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
file_menu.add_command(label="New")
file_menu.add_command(label="Open")
file_menu.add_command(label="Save")

menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
menu

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't added it to the root window. You need to do the following after creating `menu`:

```
root.configure(menu=menu)
```